# How to read some csv files in a folder in python

Tags: python, merge, export-to-csv, opencsv

There are 40 csv files; file1.csv, file2.csv. ..., file40.csv in a folder called pathImage. I want to read them, and put them in another csv file sequentially that we called 'output.csv'. The following code does not work for me.

```
im_list=[]
for i in pathImage:
    f= open(i, 'rb') 
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    header = reader.next()
    zipped = zip(*reader)
    for j in zipped[0]:       #zipped[0] is the name of images
        im_r=misc.imread("%s.png" %j)
        im_list.append(im_r)
```

I already read the previous questions, but I do not know how can I put them into another csv file?

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv('file%d.csv' % x) for x in range(1,41)])
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```